# Best way to repair ripped parasol fabric?

Tags: furniture, garden

I have a parasol whose fabric has ripped in a couple of places at the point where the metal spokes push against the canopy to make it spread out; here's the side (and closeup) where the fabric is intact:

[image: intact side]
[image: intact closeup]

And here's the side (and closeup) where it's ripped in a couple of places:

[image: ripped side]
[image: ripped closeup]

What's the best way to patch this up?  Does it require removing completely and having patches sewn onto it or is there some way I can get away with fixing it whilst keeping the canopy on there, maybe with some kind of super sticky patch?

Comment: In the olden days there used to be iron-on patches.  Usually for the knee section of pants of school boys who were a bit rough with their clothes.  Do not know they are still available.  It has been over 50 years.

Comment: Unfortunately this is furniture repair, which is off topic here. In my experience such fabric tears when it has been degraded by sunlight and rain. It'll probably need replacement. Repair costs are probably more than it's worth.

Comment: two words ... duct tape

Comment: @jsotola duct tape won't last.  Even if it sticks in place without shifting due to the adhesive getting hot in the sun, it'll wear through just like the original canvas did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks to me like the tip of the rib has simply worn through the end of the fabric "tube."  If it was me, I would take a thick piece of canvas (something closely matching in color) and hand stitch it over the end of the tube.  Might help to tape the tube closed before stitching the canvas.  Use a good heavy duty thread and needle—not for sewing clothes, something more in the line of marine thread.

You'll probably need to do the work with the umbrella closed, so you can get the canvas to reach a reasonable distance from the worn end.